# How to extract Strings from postgres in the following format {'x: 'data', 'old_x': 'Datax'}

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have the following type of data as in my rows

```
{'new_value_formatted': 'Committed/Test Transaction', 'old_value_formatted': 'Completed'}
```

I would like to have new_value_formatted & old_value_formatted as individual  columns  and data stored in columnar manner

Tried regex '(([A-Z/ ])\w+)'. Still can't isolate.

```
select a.id,a.title,additional_data,
substring(b.additional_data ->> "old_value_formatted" FROM '[0-9a-zA-Z]+')  as "Old Value", 
substring(b.additional_data ->> "new_value_formatted" FROM '[0-9a-zA-Z]+')  as "New from table a,b....
```

```
Old Value | New_Value    
__________|____________
xxxxx .   | xxxxx
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format presented here is not valid json. Json uses double quotes. If on postgresql 9.2+ I would do `replace(data,'\'','"')::json` to get valid json, taking care of quoting issues. Then you could do select `new_data ->> 'new_value_formatted'`

I used new_data as a placeholder for the valid json version.

If you need this for an older version, please come back to me.

P.s.: this is not tested, as I currently have no machine at hand.

Comment: substring((replace(b.additional_data ,'''','"')::json) ->> 'old_value_formatted' FROM '[0-9a-zA-Z /]+')  initStage,
 substring((replace(b.additional_data ,'''','"')::json) ->> 'new_value_formatted' FROM '[0-9a-zA-Z /]+')  nextStage,